# How to unit-test a Flask-Caching memoized function?

Tags: python, flask, pytest, flask-caching

I'm using:

```
Python 3.9.13
pytest==7.2.0
pytest-mock==3.10.0
Flask==2.2.2
Flask-Caching==2.0.1
```

This is my class being tested:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class NominationData:
    title: str
    url: str
    is_approved: bool
    articles: list[ArticleData]
    hooks: list[HookData]

    @staticmethod
    @cache.memoize(timeout=30)
    def from_nomination(nomination):
        """Construct a NominationData from a dyk_tools.Nomination"""
        return NominationData(
            nomination.title(),
            nomination.url(),
            nomination.is_approved(),
            [ArticleData.from_article(a) for a in nomination.articles()],
            [HookData.from_hook(h) for h in nomination.hooks()],
        )
```

I've got a unit test for `NominationData.from_nomination()` which previously worked in a non-memoized version.  Now that I've added the `@cache.memoize()` decoration, the test crashes in `flask_caching/__init__.py:870` with `AttributeError: 'Cache' object has no attribute 'app'`.  It's obvious what the problem is: I don't have a valid application context in `flask.current_app`.  The question is, what's the best way to fix that?

One possibility would be to patch flask.current_app with a mock `AppContext`, but I'm hesitant to go down that path.  Another possibility would be to split out the memoization into a distinct shim:

```
@staticmethod
@cache.memoize(timeout=30)
def from_nomination(nomination):
    return inner_from_nomination(nomination)
```

and then just call `inner_from_nomination()` in my unit test.  That should work, but just feels wrong.  Or maybe there's some cleaner way entirely?  How would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I get it.  I need to change my unit test to call the .uncached function directly:

```
-  nomination_data = NominationData.from_nomination(nomination)
+  nomination_data = NominationData.from_nomination.uncached(nomination)
```

https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_caching.Cache.memoize